# Easiest way to re-use a function without instantiation a new class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I currently have a function that looks like this:

```
public void AnimateLayoutTransform(object ControlToAnimate)
{
//Does some stuff
}
```

I use this function in a lot of different projects, so I want it to be very reusable.  So for now I have it in a .cs file, enclosed in a namespace and a class:

```
namespace LayoutTransformAnimation
{
    public class LayoutAnims
    {
        public void AnimateLayoutTransform(object ControlToAnimate)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that to use this one function in a given project, I have to do something like

```
new LayoutTransformAnimation.LayoutAnims().AnimateLayoutTransform(mygrid);
```

Which just seems like a lot of work to reuse a single function.  Is there any way to, at the very least, use the function without creating a new instance of the class?  Similar to how we can `Double.Parse()` without creating a new `double`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to make it a normal static method. An alternative - if you're using C# 3.0 or higher - is to make it an *extension method*:

```
public static class AnimationExtensions
{
    public static void AnimateLayoutTransform(this object controlToAnimate)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Then you can just write:

```
mygrid.AnimateLayoutTransform();
```

Can you specify the type of the control to animate any more precisely than "Object"? That would be nicer... for example, can you only really animate instances of [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx)? Maybe not... but if you *can* be more specific, it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

You could make it into a static method.

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: might be best to include a sample static method/class?

Answer (score 3):

I find it useful to have a static util class  with static methods in them which can be used within the project namespace.

```
public static class YourUtilsClass
{

    public static Void YourMethod()
    {
        //do your stuff
    }   

}
```

You can call it like so: `YourUtilsClass.YourMethod()`

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace LayoutTransformAnimation 
{ 
    public class LayoutAnims 
    { 
        public static void AnimateLayoutTransform(object ControlToAnimate) 
    { 
        //Do stuff 
    } 
}
```

}

```
LayoutTransformAnimation.LayoutAnims.AnimateLayoutTransform(something);
```